# how convert text file to array in javascript using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I am trying to store my text file into array using below javascript code.

here is my data.txt file

```
1252112242213213, 145212420202512232, 2165165436543213, 32462154321654+6, 3524177103640001, 3525020705700022, 352502123456789, 3525022002590001, 3525026911920003, 3525044512870003, 3525045410950002, 3525114609910001, 35413216513543213, 65132165135432
```

here is my javascript

```
$.get('data.txt', function(data) {
        //split on new lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        //create select
        JSON.stringify(lines);
        var $nik_field = $('#i_nik');
    });
```

when i want to try at least write the result into console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .split() to split a string and convert it into an array. Its like PHP's explode that you may be familiar with.

```
var data = "1252112242213213, 145212420202512232, 2165165436543213, 32462154321654+6, 3524177103640001, 3525020705700022, 352502123456789, 3525022002590001, 3525026911920003, 3525044512870003, 3525045410950002, 3525114609910001, 35413216513543213, 65132165135432";

dataArray = data.split(', ');

console.log(dataArray);
```